# How to replace few lines in gulp

Tags: gulp

I have a problem with replacing few line of codes with `gulp-replace`. Here is the code i need to do remove

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Vaadin-Icons;
  src: url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.eot);
  src: url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.woff) format("woff"), url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.ttf) format("truetype"), url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.svg#icomoon) format("svg")
}
```

I need to replace above snippet to empty white space.

Here is my gulp:

```
replace = require('gulp-replace'),

gulp.task('minify-core-styles', function() {
    gulp.src(PATH_CSS_CORE)
        .pipe(replace(vaadin_icon, ' '))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS }))
        .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(min())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH_CSS_CORE_DEST));
});
```

And in my gulp i created a variable named `vaadin_icon` which contains strings.

```
var vaadin_icon = '@font-face {' +
    'font-family: Vaadin-Icons;' +
    'src: url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.eot);' +
    'src: url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons' +
    '.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.woff) format("woff"), url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.ttf) format("truetype"), url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.svg#icomoon) format("svg")' +
    '}';
```

What did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not accounting for the newlines or tabs/spaces in your @font-face declaration.  So try:

```
var vaadin_icon = '@font-face {\r\n' +
  '  font-family: Vaadin-Icons;\r\n' +
  '  src: url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.eot);\r\n' +
  '  src: url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons' +
  '.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.woff) format("woff"), url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.ttf) format("truetype"), url(../valo/fonts/vaadin-icons/Vaadin-Icons.svg#icomoon) format("svg")\r\n' +
'}';
```

Note I do not know which OS you are using, so you might have to try something besides `\r\n` for the newlines.  You might also be able to do this with template literals.

EDIT:  Also it is easier to just use a regex in your case.

```
var fontFaceRegEx = /@font-face.*(.*\r\n)*}/g;
```

and then in the replace pipe use:

```
.pipe(replace(fontFaceRegEx, ' '))
```

Comment: I am using window. And its still the same :)

Comment: i mean windows*

Comment: Works perfectly for me.  On Windows.  Are those spaces or tabs?  If tabs, try \t instead of the two spaces at the beginning .  In any case, I modified the answer above to use the simpler regex.